# UIImageView, constraints and a blur programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I want to create a UIImageView with a blur and constraints. But the blur doesn't want to work with constraints.

My code:

```
    var notifBackground: UIImageView!
    notifBackground = UIImageView()
    notifBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    view.addSubview(notifBackground)

    notifBackground.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    notifBackground.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    notifBackground.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    notifBackground.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    notifBackground.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    let blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.regular))
    blur.frame = notifBackground.bounds
    view.addSubview(blur)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time you're setting the bounds of the blur to the same bounds of the imageview, the layout constraints has not been processed yet.
What you have to do is to set similar constraints to the blur as well. By doing this, the blur will have similar bounds and appear on top of the imageview.

Answer (score 0):

**BLUR EFFECT**

```
let blur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.regular)
            let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blur)
            blurView.frame = view.bounds
            blurView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            view.addSubview(blurView)
```